# C - RegQueryValueEx sometimes in Release build

Tags: c, debugging, winapi, registry, release

This is driving me crazy. I'm compiling my project on Visual Studio 2012. I want to read a `REG_BINARY` registry entry using `RegOpenKeyEx` and `RegQueryValueEx` calls. In Debug (Multi-Threaded Debug) mode, everything works perfectly. However, in Release (Multi-Threaded) mode, `RegQueryValueEx` will VERY often fail with error code `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. Here is the code I am using:

```
HKEY keyHandle;
TCHAR lpData[1024];

DWORD lpcbData;

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &keyHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"fail", L"title", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
} else if (RegQueryValueEx(keyHandle, L"DigitalProductId", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)lpData, &lpcbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"fail!", L"title", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}

MessageBox(NULL, L"success", L"title", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the definition of RegQueryValueEx, lpcbData is both an *In* and *Out* parameter. That is, RegQueryValueEx both reads it and writes to it. It complains because you are passing it without initializing it first with the size of the buffer, which in your case is 1024 (also I recommend that you change TCHAR to BYTE as required by the API; You can convert it to a Unicode string later on).

Try setting it to 1024 before calling the function. If *then* it fails with ERROR_MORE_DATA, then your buffer is not big enough - in other words, the registry key string is too long - you can either define it to contain more characters, or, better yet, call the function first with a NULL parameter instead of the buffer, and you will get back in lpcbData the required size of the buffer. You can then allocate the required buffer on the heap. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mints97 To answer the question that's driving you crazy: It appears to work in Debug builds, since Debug builds initialize memory with a bit pattern (0xcccccccc) to more easily spot uninitialized memory. This value is large enough to read your registry data in one go. It is also larger than your actual buffer size. In Release builds uninitialized memory contains whatever a previous write operation left there. Memory that has not been previously written to holds the value 0. Passing 0 as the `lpcbData` argument with a non-NULL `lpData` inevitably leads to `ERROR_MORE_DATA`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `lpcbData` before calling `RegQueryValueEx()`.  You have to tell it how large `lpData` is, in bytes, so it knows how many bytes it can retreive.

```
DWORD lpcbData = sizeof(lpData);
```

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx):

> lpcbData [in, out, optional]
>
> **A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. When the function returns, this variable contains the size of the data copied to lpData.**

A better option is to ask the Registry how large the data is, then (re)allocate the buffer as needed.  The example in the documentation shows you how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try buffer size reallocation!

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `lpcbData` to size of your buffer before passing it to `RegQueryValueEx()`.

Sample code:

```
HKEY keyHandle;
TCHAR lpData[1024];

DWORD lpcbData= sizeof(lpData); //set size.

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &keyHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"fail", L"title", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
} else if (RegQueryValueEx(keyHandle, L"DigitalProductId", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)lpData, &lpcbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(NULL, L"fail!", L"title", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}
```

Its working by chance so that `lpcData` contains some random value which is higher than the actual size of data. And probably your data is not more than 1024.

Moreover, if you get `ERROR_MORE_DATA` error, the `lpcData` will indicate how much size is required to read the data. So you should update your buffer accordingly and retry.